# Axios CORS only on invalid request

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, axios

I deployed a lambda function to AWS for a simple login endpoint and have it hooked up to API gateway. I am using axios in a Vue client to connect to it. For some reason, when I send valid credentials, everything works just fine. However, when I send invalid credentials, I get the following CORS error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://MY_ENDPOINT.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/staging/login' from origin 'http://localhost:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Following is my lambda function:

```js
exports.loginHandler = async (event) => {
  if (event.email === "testemail@example.com" && event.password === "password") {
    return {
      message: "Successful login"
    };
  }
  throw new Error("Invalid login credentials");
};
```

Following is my function that is called when the Vue login form is filled out:

```js
import axios from "axios";

async function loginAction({ email, password }) {
  try {
    const resp = await axios.post(
      "https://MY_ENDPOINT.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/staging/login",
      {
        email,
        password
      }
    );
    return resp;
  } catch (err) {
    // This just logs "Network error"
    console.log(err.message);
  }
}
```

I set up a mapping template to return a 400 error that looks like `{ message: "Invalid login credentials" }` when the Error is thrown in the lambda function. In Postman, the error is handled just fine, but not in the browser. For invalid credentials, the OPTIONS query executes with a 200.

Like I said, there are no issues when I provide the valid credentials but I get that CORS error with invalid credentials. Does anyone have an explanation for this?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Comment: If you get a lambda error, API gateway will return a CORS error. Not sure why, but yeah, it is confusing. It is best to handle error inside the lambda and provide a valid response.

Comment: More info on lambda proxy integration if that is what you are using: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/handle-errors-in-lambda-integration.html

Comment: Ah I found it. I had to add an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in my method response and a header mapping with a value of '*' in my Integration response in API gateway.